# My CPU usage is unnecessarily high while creating a C program in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: cpu, programming

I have an MSI GE60 2PC Apache model Gamebook. I also use it for my collage work. It runs Ubuntu 14.10. I have a CPU usage problem while creating a ".c" file. I use the default text editor; while I code, CPU usage goes 60-65%. My CPU is Intel core i7 4710HQ.

Comment: I tried with emacs it didn't happen.

Comment: What does `top` say is using all the cpu?

Answer (score 2):

As a possible solution I suggest removing `ibus`. It [has been reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1299759) that is causing issues with `gedit`. To do that, run:

```
sudo apt-get remove ibus
```

Then reboot, to be sure, and check if the problem went away.

Comment: the problem is CPU usage and you give solution remove software for input.

Comment: @virusvsveer: this is a reported issue, and the only remedy is to remove ibus.  If you don't know about it, please don't downvote!

Comment: I know that very vary well but in this problem that's not proper solution.

Comment: Then give him the proper solution... /me out

Comment: @Frantique It might help if you could link to the existing report.

Comment: @Frantique sorry for the vote down but as me its not proper solution and author can not give me a full detail that's why I am not able to give answer.

Comment: Thank you for edit, Oli, I didn't had the exact location, just remembered that I've seen it before.

Comment: try to open gnome-system-monitor as root, and then go to "processes" tab, it may point out the process responsible for high CPU usage. **NOTE** that some infinite loops may cause High CPU usage, so coding properly may help no matter what IDE/text editor you are using

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to choose *none* for "Keyboard Input Method System" in System Settings -> Language Support.

This list enables (or disables) so called “Input Method Editors” (IME). They are needed where multiple key-strokes should result in one letter/character and you need graphical feedback about the selection and confirmation process (e.g. a list to choose from). This is used for Chinese and Japanese, because they have thousands of characters.

With normal keyboards languages, like Russian, Greek and all the others which don’t need more than about 100 characters/letters can use other tricks to get to the goal. “Dead keys”, AltGr for example, or simply Shift.
from: [What do the 4 keyboard input method systems mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20982/what-do-the-4-keyboard-input-method-systems-mean)

Comment: Please explain what this solution does.