# Return key stops functioning correctly when switching to a new language

Tags: keyboard, input-language, hebrew

I have set up a new language (Hebrew) in my Ubuntu 18.04.

When I switch to it, I noticed that return key doesn't work correctly. For example, when i'm in any chat and typing in Hebrew and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, instead of the message being sent, nothing happens.

And it's not just the return key. For example, I often use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close browser tabs and they stop working when in Hebrew as well.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: happens to me as well. I noticed that if I click the chat area, then return key works. also, it's working correctly in firefox, the problem is with chrome (also incognito).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar problem and found a solution.

Open the language support and change the "Keyboard input method system" to "none".
[image]

It was "IBus" on my computer and when I changed it to "none" and reboot, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key send messages as expected. same for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

the IBus is used for languages that need multiple keystrokes (Japanese, Chinese (various) and Korean). see [What do the 4 keyboard input method systems mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20982/what-do-the-4-keyboard-input-method-systems-mean) for more details.

Comment: Amazing, solved a very annoying issue for me. Thanks.